# SQL export specific data from certain columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, export

I've got this ID grabbing script that grabs id's using proxys and i'm having a little trouble figuring out how to edit this scrips, i've already got it so it only exports the id's where "rare = 1" but how do i edit it so it doesn't export the ID's where "sold = 1" this way it only exports ID's that haven't been sold.

```
$ids = $sql->select('*', '`ids` where rare = 1 (i dont want it to export values where sold = 1) ORDER BY `UserId` ASC', NULL, NULL, NULL, true, true);
```

Comment: `rare = 1 & sold = 1` to use this simple

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `<>` (Not equal to) clause for sold.

```
$ids = $sql->select('*', '`ids` where rare = 1 AND sold <> 1 ) ORDER BY `UserId` ASC', NULL, NULL, NULL, true, true);
```